# Altering the "Status report" page

Tags: 7

The hosting provider I user for my site disabled the `phpinfo()` function and, as consequence, the link that would normally appear in the status report page is not anymore shown, replaced by a warning message.

I would like to create a custom module to remove that message, and show a link to a page that, similarly to the page shown by `phpinfo()`, reports information about PHP and the enabled extensions.
Is there a way to alter the information about PHP [system_requirements()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.install/function/system_requirements/7) normally shows in that page?

Comment: No, we don't have a `hook_requirements_alter()`. That would do a nice feature request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may not be able to alter the system_requirements array directly, but you can hack around it in the theme layer by implementing [theme_status_report](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.admin.inc/function/theme_status_report/7).

```
 theme('status_report', array('requirements' => $requirements));
```

Comment: In a module you can use hook_preprocess_status_report

Comment: Since I needed it in a module, I used `hook_preprocess_status_report()`.